# How to ask politely someone to not call me 'Sir'?

Tags: employer-relations

In my office, a newly recruited employee calls me 'Sir'.  How can I politely ask him not to call me 'Sir'?

It appears to be simple, but I am finding it hard to address this issue.

Comment: Believe it or not, some folks really do **not** like being called sir.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about navigating the workplace.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings Sure it does.  If you have a co-worker calling you sir....

Comment: @MisterPositive - There is nothing about this question or the proper answers to it, that does not change if you remove the in the workplace concept though... that means its not about the workplace.  Better asked on IPS and IMO it does not belong here.  I am but a single vote though.

Comment: Is this person calling you sir in someway preventing you from doing your job?  Is there some reason that the general public would generally agree that you should take offense at being called sir or that this person should be aware that calling you sir is inapproriate(ie you are not presenting as male)

Comment: As someone who had a habit of calling my boss "sir" and was told not to, remember that it make take some time for the employee to break the habit.

Comment: Is there anyone in your office who goes by "sir" or other honorifics? That really makes a difference in how you should approach this.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings - maybe a migration to the interpersonal relations stack might be a better suggestion than closing?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Only mods can migrate. You're welcome to flag it if you think it belongs there.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you do it, yourself, I was just noting that you were stating the case for closing when a migration might be an alternative.

Comment: It actually is very much about the workplace because being in the workplace has different ramifications than in a store or other environments. There's a different level of tact involved for obvious reasons. voting to reopen.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - I have no objection if they want the question.  But it definately does not belong here

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would fit well on IPS, if OP wants to migrate it. However, you would need to add more information about the cultural background and what you have already tried.

Comment: Easy, "You can call me <First Name>"

Comment: This would be an answer if the question wasn't on hold: It is possible that your colleague perceives subtle social hints that it would be appropriate to call you "Sir". For example, our clothes communicate social hints about us. Someone wearing a sharp suit, dress shirt, tie and immaculately polished business shoes is more likely to be called "Sir" than a person in Jeans, sneakers and a two year old T-shirt. Clothes, after all, sometimes reflect roles, e.g. manager vs. developer. If you like to be approached less formally, you could try to appear less formal (if you don't already).

Comment: Is this person just another employee or do they report to you, or are clearly subordinate to you in some way?

Comment: Is the issue them calling you "sir" rather than "ma'am"? If so, you may want to discuss it with HR.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> How can i politely ask him not to call me Sir ?

I always laugh and say "Please call me Joe."

That almost always works. (Although you should probably use your first name rather than "Joe").

Comment: And here was me about to call my boss "Joe"...  Glad you clarified that.  :D

Comment: “Certainly, Sir Joe!”

Comment: @Snow I see you're in a Joevial mood ;)

Comment: That will work for most people. You will meet a few people who have an ingrained since childhood habit of using "Sir" or "Ma'am" for anyone they regard as being in a senior position relative to them. I've asked at least one person to call me "Patricia" instead of "Ma'am" several times, and I've just given up.

Comment: The key is to tell them what to call you instead. If you just say "don't call me Sir" they don't know if they have guessed your gender wrong and prefer Ma'am, or prefer Mr X, or Joe, or "dude" or what. They may end up staring at the floor a lot, not calling you anything, and feeling very uncomfortable.

Comment: Just don't call me Shirley. ;)

Answer (score 6):

> How can i politely ask him not to call me Sir ?

In my experience, these two approaches have worked well if done in a in a tongue in cheek manner:

"*Please do not call me sir, my Dad is a sir, I am just a regular guy.*"

Or

"*I am not an officer, please do not call me sir.*"

**Followed by:** "Please call me [*whatever you prefer here*]".

Rinse and repeat, eventually they should get it.

Comment: Unless he's dating your daughter, when you do become a Sir.

Comment: as of now, dont have daughter.  :)

Answer (score 4):

As has been said, simply ask that they call you something else. Name, boss, whatever. The problem you're going to face is that, for some, it's an ingrained reaction. In some cultures it's a given that you say "sir" or "ma'am" or some other honorific (`~san", "~senpai", "~sama" in Japanese for example) , and it's been drilled into you for most of your lifetime.

It might be a considerable struggle for that person to remember to call you "Joe". Just remember that if you get frustrated with his continued use of "Sir". I am usually very careful when I speak to a boss when I first get to a job, and continue to say "Sir" and "Ma'am" for a while before I relax into the "daily grind"

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Stand straight, raise your voice to a commanding tone, and snarl **"At *ease* private!".** Then you grin, wait for his grin and high five him. That should solve it.

Comment: This could backfire if the employee doesn't get it at first or either doesn't have a great sense of humor, and trust a few takes it way to personally...

Comment: This could definitely go sideways on you IMO.

Comment: @William-H-M (and Mister P.): Yes, but if it goes right it can be the beginning of a wonderful friendship. No risk, no gain.

Comment: Only do this if you happen to know (at least for *some* time) that person, or if you see people are sir-ing you for a tease. Otherwise, this may startle people that are genuinely calling you sir.

Comment: After 12 years of having to call every authority figure "Sir" or "Miss" at school or be subject to detention for not showing proper respect I found it very difficult when I got my first job to adapt. A few weeks before I would have been writing a letter of apology and explaining to my parents why they were called at work and suddenly you're ridiculed by older colleagues for doing the opposite. This is not the way to go, especially if the employee is new to the job and nervous. They're only trying to be respectful and this could easily be taken the wrong way

Comment: @LordJebusVII What you describe would make me leave the school (because this will be just one of the many things you learn there that has no relation to anything outside the school and will not be useful there), and possibly the state or the country if that is commonplace.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - teenagers rarely get a say in where they go to school. For adults I agree it's unacceptable and you don't have to put up with it, but new starters may have come straight from school into the workplace and never had the option to go anywhere else.

Comment: Same idea, I prefer: "Don't call me sir, I work for a living".

Answer (score 0):

At my company there is a rule, whoever calls someone sir or madam if they don't want to be addressed that way, the person has to treat the whole office. After this rule, things have changed :)